# Code in \lstlisting breaks document (compile error)

Tags: errors, listings, compiling

I want to show a JSON object in my document. If I do the following, it works:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
{
  "id": "5",
  "key": "discardedCard"
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

But if I extend the code to the following, then there are only errors when compiling the document:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
{
  "id": "5",
  "key": "discardedCard",
  "value": {
    "suit": "DIAMONDS",
    "rank": "QUEEN"
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

**Error log:**

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 19.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.19     "
          suit": "DIAMONDS",
A forbidden control sequence occurred in skipped text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 19.
```

I'd like to provide a MWE but if I run the code in a MWE then it works. So it looks like there are other parts in my bachelor thesis which break the document.

Is there a way to output code in a listing in a secure way or maybe escaped?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I would guess you have a language shorthand (babel?) that defines `"` to do something, you can locally turn shorthands off, which might help.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I thought this is related to france. Benny lives in Germany ;-)

Comment: Thank you David! Yes, I use babel. The problem was that the name of my chapter was "\chapter{Implementation of "`Jiga"'}". I changed it to "\chapter{Implementation of Jiga}" which removed the error.

Comment: There is no relation to babel. :-)

Comment: Using double quotes in LaTeX text is normally a mistake...

Comment: voted to re-open as it was never "too localised" anyway and as noted in a comment on my answer today, it still comes up now.

Answer (score 7):

I would guess you have a language shorthand (babel?) that defines `"` to do something, you can locally turn shorthands off, which might help

Comment: I had the same problem and it was related to the place of \usepackage[francais]{babel}. Solved the problem when I put it before \usepackage{listings} in preamble.

Comment: @Penbeuz That's it! Exactly the same problem (babel francais).  Merci!