# Should babel package call be placed at the end of the preamble?

Tags: best-practices, babel, incompatibility, preamble

I remember to have read few year ago<sup>1</sup> that `babel` line<sup>2</sup> should be placed at the end of the preamble in order to avoid problems with other packages. (I believe `hyperref` package should also be placed at the end of the preamble for the same reason.)

However, I see, in MWEs, the `babel` line often just after the `\documentclass`.

**Is there any differences? What is the good practice here?**

### Addendum

Here is my LaTeX template. Do you see any other misplaced packages calls in general?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,hyperref,backend=biber,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,date=year]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\bibliography{biblio}
\title{}
\author{}
\usepackage[francais,english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\onehalfspacing


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

<sub>1. I don't remember where... Sorry.</sub>

<sub>2.`\usepackage[dutch,english]{babel}`</sub>

Comment: I usually place it early in the preamble, so other packages can pickup its settings.

Comment: I always put it third, after `fontenc` and `inputenc`.

Comment: @egreg thanks but is there some guideline here? and if yes, what is the reasons?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some packages behave differently, or adapt themselves somehow, if `babel` has already been loaded or not: for instance  `biblatex`, `csquotes`, `datetime`, `fmtcount`, `glossaries`, `listings` `microtype`, `natbib`, `tikz`, to name the most used. So it's best to load `babel` as soon as possible.

I tend to group package calls by category. First the ones that directly involve the main choices for my document:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % alphabets to prepare
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % input encoding
\usepackage[italian]{babel} % language(s)

\usepackage{kpfonts}        % or another font package

\usepackage{geometry}       % if needed for page shape
\geometry[<options>]

\usepackage{fancyhdr}       % if needed (it should go after geometry)
<fancyhdr settings>
```

Then I load the other utility packages in a possibly meaningful order:

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{csquotes}            % for biblatex, mainly
\usepackage[<options>]{biblatex} % or natbib
```

and so on. Of course, `hyperref` should be last, but `cleveref` should go after it, if loaded.

Note: `kpfonts` is just by way of example. I'm not generally tied to a particular font.

If `etex` becomes necessary, it should go *first*. Other packages to be loaded early are of course `ifpdf`, `ifxetex` and `ifluatex`, when needed.

Command definitions and other settings go after all packages have been loaded.

Comment: You can add `listings` to your package list that should be load after `babel`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100717/code-in-lstlisting-breaks-document-compile-error/100719#comment341860_100719

Comment: @quinmars I did a rather coarse `grep` for `\@ifpackageloaded{babel}` and `listings` didn't show up. I'll add it, because it's very frequently loaded.

Comment: I actually don't know why changing the order helps, but it seems to be related to the babel shorthands. But I don't know much about how this is handle internally.

Comment: Well the "behaves differently" is more like a *works* or *works not* for `listings`.

Comment: @quinmars "adapt themselves" applies.