# Error in some rare circumstances: babel with french option after listings, active character in moving argument, code in listing across pages

Tags: listings, page-breaking, french, active-characters

**Edit:** I have edited my question which initially wrongly focused on labels.

This question is related to [Code in \lstlisting breaks document (compile error)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100717/18401). Let us consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Foo ; bar}
\end{figure}
%
\lipsum[1-4]%
%
\begin{lstlisting}
Foo 1
Foo 2
Foo 3
Foo 4
Foo 5
Foo 6
Foo 7
Foo 8
Foo 9
\end{lstlisting}
%
\end{document}
```

When compiled with `pdflatex`, it gives the error:

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 15.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.23 Foo 
         9
?
```

Strangely enough, the error doesn't arise as soon as either:

- the listing doesn't cross pages (e.g. by removing `Foo 9`),
- `babel` is used with another language than `french`,
- `;` in the caption argument (which, I guess, is a moving argument) is replaced by a non active character of `frenchb` (anything different from `;:!?`),
- `listings` package is loaded after `babel`.

So, there are several workarounds but I' like to understand what's going on and to know if there is a way to consistently get rid of this bug.

Comment: Avoiding colons in labels?

Comment: I replace `:` with `-`, which is not made an active character by `frenchb`.

Comment: Yes, this is a workaround I mentioned but it doesn't explain what's going on. Moreover, investigating a bit more, I discovered the trouble with active character isn't only related to labels but, if I'm right, to moving arguments. I'll edited my question in this respect.

Comment: Well, don't load `babel` after `listings`.

Comment: @egreg Okay, okay :) But, AFAIK, `listings` was not in the small list of packages that should come after `babel`. Moreover, the circumstances under which it seems to be necessary are pretty strange and special. Hence, if no consistent fix emerges from my question, let us consider it as a record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here in short whats going on.

The colon is defined as `\active@prefix :\active@char:`. This definition is so that under certain conditions (e.g. in a protected@write, or when `\if@safe@actives` is true
(which is the case in `\@newl@bel`)) the `:` expands to something that it "safe" in a label.

But in your example `:` no longer has this safe definition as listings stepped in. 
listings redefines the `:`:

```
 \def :{\lst@ProcessOther :}
```

So in the output routine (when the label is written to the aux), the `:` has no "safe" definition and break.

It works if you load listings after babel, as listings is resetting definitions after every line and so now the babel definition is active in the output.

But you should be aware that any redefinition of `:` can break the label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}%
\begin{document}
\rule{0.4pt}{.805\textheight}\par
\section{Listing}
\tracingmacros=1
\label{secccc:listing}
%
Foo
Foo 1
Foo 2
Foo 3\def:{~}
Foo 4
\end{document}
```

So active chars in labels are inherently unsafe.

Comment: I guess what you said about labels remains true for moving arguments like `\caption` (as I changed in the current edit of my question)?

Comment: Yes quite probably. The caption is written to the lof in the output routine.

Comment: Looking in the code I just saw that you can tell listings to update the catcode with `\lstset{rescanchars=;:}`

Comment: Nice! But, AFAICS, declaring this globally isn't enough and hence, potentially, it should be inserted before each listing.