# Node label location taken literally when defining Circuitikz macro with babel french

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, circuitikz, babel-french

I'm using the same variant of a circuit multiple times, with only minor changes, so I defined a macro with tikz commands. Here's my document:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{babel} % fixes some other bug with tikz and babel french

\begin{document}
    \newcommand\circuitbase{
        \draw (2.5,4) node[label={above:$c$}] {} to[R, a=$\SI{2}{\kilo\ohm}$, *-] (2.5,2)
        node[label={left:$a$}] {} to[R, a=$\SI{1}{\kilo\ohm}$, *-*] (2.5,0) node[label={below:$d$}] {};
    }

    \begin{circuitikz}[american]
        \circuitbase
        \draw (2.5,2) to[R, l=$\SI{470}{\ohm}$] (5,2);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

However the node labels don't work correctly when using the macro:

[image: preview]

This is most likely due to babel being set to French, because it works with `\usepackage{babel}`. How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/28557)? I am not able to reproduce this.

Comment: Yes sorry, first time posting here. It seems to be due to babel french.

Comment: Found this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236751/error-in-some-rare-circumstances-babel-with-french-option-after-listings-activ. Colon is an active char in french it seems, I think a space gets inserted before and the label location fails to be parsed. I'll look more into it tomorrow.

Comment: You can use `node[left] {$a$}` instead of `node[label={left:$a$}] {}` if that's an option.

Comment: babel-french has the `\NoAutoSpacing` command for these cases, please see the documentation.   Code ` {\NoAutoSpacing\circuitbase}` or add `\NoAutoSpacing` to the`\circuitbase` command itself.

Comment: @DanielFlipo probably your answer is better than mine, which is using a hammer --- would you mind posting one?

Comment: @nidhin Thanks, I didn't know you could do it this way. That works for me.

Answer (score 2):

(Notice that probably [@DanielFlipo answer-in-comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/69978/daniel-flipo) is a better solution --- I hope he'll post an answer; mine below is to just cut the `:` functionality in babel-french)

This is an interaction between the active chars in `babel` (I suspect the colon), and it's not `circuitikz` specific at all. This "more minimal example" also shows the problem:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel} % fixes some other bug with tikz and babel french

\begin{document}
    \newcommand\circuitbase{
        \draw (2.5,4) node[label={above:$c$}] {} ;
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \circuitbase
        \draw (5,4) node[label={above:$c$}] {} ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you do not need shorthands, the better solution is to use

```
\usepackage[french, shorthands=off]{babel}
```

and then use the Unicode characters for French letters and accents (although I do not know what `:` is supposed to do in French, so I can be wrong here).

Comment: This certainly works but the active colon is also nice to have. It doesn't do much except adding a space before it, but that's pretty useful.

Comment: Yes, I agree --- let's see if @daniel-flipo can post a better answer

Comment: I just used the alternative syntax without the colon `node[left] {$a$}`.

Answer (score 2):

With pdflatex, the colon is made active by babel-french in order to add automatically the space required in French before it (same for ; ! ?).
The \NoAutoSpacing command is provided for cases where insertion of a space is not wanted.

But adding `\NoAutoSpacing` to the `\circuitbase` command (best in a group) would only remove the spurious space:

```
\newcommand\circuitbase{\bgroup\NoAutoSpacing
   \draw (2.5,4) node[label={above:$c$}] {} to[R, a=$\SI{2}{\kilo\ohm}$, *-] (2.5,2)
   node[label={left:$a$}] {} to[R, a=$\SI{1}{\kilo\ohm}$, *-*] (2.5,0) node[label={below:$d$}] {};
                        \egroup}
```

I guess that is not what you want. Switching locally to say "english" would not help either (the colon remains active).

Please note that your original command `\circuitbase` works out of the box when compiling with lualatex or xelatex which do not make active high punctuation characters in French.

With pdflatex `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` should fix this issue, but it doesn't.